# How do I get friends gender using facebook api and fql

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new to PHP and FQL. I know how it needs to be done, but don't know the codes. Creating an application where user sees only the opposite gender in  box.

I got up to getting the the user's name, gender and friends id. Now I need help running the FQL to and getting the gender of all the friends and insert the names of the opposite gender in .

```
<?php  
    $fbuser = $facebook->api('/me');//getting users data
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends'); //getting friends data (only gives id and name)
    $userName = $fbuser['name'];//getting users name
    $userGender =  $fbuser['gender'];//getting users gender

    $friendsId = array();//empyt array to insert friends id
    foreach ($friends['data'] as $value);{ //loop
        array_push($friendsId, $value['id']); // not sure if this correct

        $friendsGender = friendsGender ;//run FQL to get the friends gender using the id

        //conditional Statement, if users and friends gender is not same insert the friends name in <select>

?>
```

---

I did the following but it didn't work. Is my second line of script correct?

```
$friendsInfo = $facebook->api('/me/friends', array('fields' => 'id,name,gender'));
$friendsGender = $friendsInfo['gender'];
echo $friendsGender;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get a friend's data by:

```
foreach ($friends['data'] as $value){
    $friend = $facebook->api('/'+$value['id']);
```

But that's very inefficient. Luckily there's another solution - you can specify which fields you want facebook to return:

```
$facebook->api('/me/friends', array('fields' => 'id,name,gender'));
```

PS. it's graph api calls; fql is something else

PPS. `foreach ($friends['data'] as $value);{` is buggy - the block is outside/after the loop

Comment: I did the following but it didn't work. Is my second line of script correct?

    $friendsInfo = $facebook->api('/me/friends', array('fields' => 'id,name,gender'));
    $friendsGender = $friendsInfo['gender'];
    echo $friendsGender;

Comment: 1) the [graph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=681269637) is your friend. 2) `$friendInfo['gender']` is undefined because `$friendInfo` is an array of friends -- use the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like:

```
<?php

$access_token = 'AABBCC...';
$param = array(
    'access_token'  => $access_token,
    'method'        => 'GET',
    'q'             => 'SELECT name, sex FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'
);

$fql = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?' . http_build_query($param);


$res = file_get_contents($fql);
$aRes = json_decode($res, 1);
```

You can even choose to filter adding `WHERE sex = "female" AND uid IN (..)` to your query